# How can I prove that $\left|\sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i \binom{a}{i} \binom{n-a}{r-i}\right| \leq \binom{n}{r}$?

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, spectral-graph-theory

This is a conjecture:

> How can I prove that
>
> \begin{equation}
> \left|\sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i \binom{a}{i} \binom{n-a}{r-i}\right| \leq \binom{n}{r}
> \end{equation}
>
> for $0\leq a \leq n$, $0\leq r \leq n$ and $n,r,a \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{r}\left(-1\right)^{r}\dbinom{a}{i}\dbinom{n-a}{r-i}\right|\leq\sum_{i=0}^{r}\dbinom{a}{i}\dbinom{n-a}{r-i}=\dbinom{n}{r}
 $$ where the last identity follows from the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html).

Comment: Thank you Marco, I did not know that identy!

Comment: @ilmarchese You're welcome.

Comment: @ilmarchese you may like to upvote this answer, given that it is a good one and you accepted it as a solution.